# How to download information from a Facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I'm trying to find something that is written on one of my pages. It's not on my own Facebook wall, it's on the wall of one of my pages. How can I download the whole webpage so that I don't have to keep scrolling down to find what I'm looking for? Or is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

You can download the entire archive of your Facebook profile by going to [Settings](http://www.facebook.com/settings) and then clicking on `Download a copy of your Facebook data` (the last option in the list after `Language`). Beware, this will take a long time to download if you have many photos uploaded.

Comment: It's not on my own page, it's on one of my other pages.

Comment: Settings doesn't show up when I'm using facebook as a page.

Comment: Oh, sorry - I missed the part that it's a business page. There's no way to search or download content from a Page.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is a bit unclear to me but if you're looking *download the whole webpage*, you can just right-click on anywhere on the webpage and choose "Save Page As" (on Firefox), "Save As" (on Chrome) or simply press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and save that particular webpage.

If you remember a certain word or a phrase of what you're searching, just go to that page and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (both browsers) which brings up the search bar. Then type in in the search space and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: I don't think that's going to get the information I'm looking for because it's several pages down.

Answer (score -2):

Use Archivedbook.

From their Q&A:

> **Does it work with Facebook Pages and Groups?**
>
> Yes! In your browser's address bar, just replace "www.facebook.com" by "archivedbook.com". This is not an official feature and doesn't work efficiently (yet) on pages with more than thousands of posts.

Comment: A link to their site where this FAQ information is posted would be helpful as well.  Thanks!

Comment: No longer working as of April 2015.  http://archivedbook.com/this-is-the-end